# Background color transition when i leave the activity

Tags: android

i am currently developing an app which have a log in activity and a registration activity. In the log in activity i have a color transition background like the one in instagram. Problem is wen i leave the activity (say i go to a sign up activity) and come back again, the animation starts from the first color of the background. I want the background to continue to animate even if i leave the activity and continue to whatever color it has reached.
I implemented a sliding animation from and to my activities.
So in short, if my starting color is red and i navigate away from my activity and when i come back it should not start from start(red). It should continue to whatever color.
NT: i tried giving it a launchMode of singleInstance it didnt work

Comment: Please show us some code so we can grasp what the problem is.

Comment: There is couple ways to do it. What you tried so far ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz i tried puting launchMode to "singleInstance"

Comment: @MosheRabaev thnx... Will do so

Answer (score 0):

are you using lifecycle. if yes then in OnResume method start this animation again but plus one poistion.. 
like if you use i++ for image switcher you need to increment i with +1 in onResume.
post your code so we can analyse the problem.